# mod_rewrite - redirect to a different url based on existence of x_wap_profile header

Tags: mod-rewrite

We have a desktop and a mobile version of our webapp.
The desktop url is more prominent and so we would like to redirect the user to the mobile version in case the request is for the desktop url from a mobile device.

In the apache config we have the mod_rewrite module
 and my config at present looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{x-wap-profile} ^https?://
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://google.com [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

At this point this is the only rewrite rule that we have so I'm not sure if L is required because this is the first and last rule anyway.

I have just indicated redirection to google.com for testing purposes

I'm not sure if my condition check is right.I couldn't figure out how to check for existence of a header.Is that what is wrong?If yes,please let me know how to specify the RewriteCond

How I'm Testing?
I'm testing from a Firefox browser and using the Modify headers plugin to simulate the mobile request.I'm adding the x_wap_profile header.
However I don't see any redirect happening with this config.Can you please let me know where I'm going wrong?I would also appreciate if there is any logging that can be introduced here to verify if this rule is being trigerred.I don't see any errors though with the current modified config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for an arbitrary header in mod_rewrite (i.e. a header not in [this list](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)), the syntax is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} ^.+
RewriteRule .* http://google.com [L,R]


piotrek@piotrek-Vostro-2520:~/vhosts/localhost$ curl http://localhost/
OKOK
piotrek@piotrek-Vostro-2520:~/vhosts/localhost$ curl -H 'x-wap-profile: abcd' http://localhost/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://google.com">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Change it to make it work for https inside header.

Docs here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond in section `Other things you should be aware of:`.